# Opencv moving pattern generation

Tags: python, opencv, animation, design-patterns

Hi all im new to opencv and python and i have the following code:

````
```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def Vstripes(width, height, num_stripes, color1, color2, speed):

    image = np.ones((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
    # Calculate the width of each stripe
    stripe_width = width // num_stripes
    # Calculate the starting horizontal shift
    start_shift = 0

    while True:

        # Draw the vertical stripes with the current horizontal shift
        for i in range(num_stripes):

            # Calculate the starting and ending x-coordinates of each stripe with the shift
            start_x = (i * stripe_width + start_shift) % width
            end_x = ((i + 1) * stripe_width + start_shift) % width
            # Draw the stripe with the specified color
            color = color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2
            image[:, start_x:end_x, :] = color


        cv2.imshow("Moving Vertical Stripes", image)

        key = cv2.waitKey(50)  # Adjust the delay time between frames (in milliseconds)


        # Check for key press (break the loop if any key is pressed)
        if key != -1:

            break


        # Update the horizontal shift for the next frame

        start_shift = (start_shift + speed) % (width * num_stripes)


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Set the parameters
width = 800
height = 600
num_stripes = 10
color1 = (255, 0, 0)  # Blue
color2 = (0, 0, 0)  # Black
num_frames = 1000  # Number of frames for the animation
speed = 1  # Speed of the vertical movement
# Generate and display the moving stripes infinitely (press any key to stop)

Vstripes(width, height, num_stripes, color1, color2, speed)
```
````

What this code does is it creates stripe dimensions from the given parameters, and then alternate the colors. then it will move from left to right until it reaches the end and then it resets. this is where i have a small issue where when it resets, the moving pattern does not look like its always moving from left to right. like it resets but it is blocky(? idk how to explain it correctly).  any idea how i can go about fixing it? i want it so that the generated pattern looks as if it moves from left to right indefinitely.

i tried editing start_x line as well as image line but i didnt get the result i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you need to handle edge cases: the first and the last stripe. Suppose at some moment `start_shift = 73`. Then `start_x` and `end_x` will have the following values:

```
73 153
153 233
233 313
313 393
393 473
473 553
553 633
633 713
713 793
793 73
```

If you use the code `image[:, start_x:end_x, :] = color` then:

1. Pixels from 0 to 73 will not be updated
2. `image[:, 793:73, :]` will not update any pixels.

Easiest way is to use [numpy.roll function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). Full example:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def Vstripes(width, height, num_stripes, color1, color2, speed):
    image = np.ones((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
    # Calculate the width of each stripe
    stripe_width = width // num_stripes

    for i in range(num_stripes):
        color = color1 if i % 2 == 0 else color2
        image[:, i * stripe_width : (i + 1) * stripe_width, :] = color

    while True:
        image = np.roll(image, shift=speed, axis=1)
        cv2.imshow("Moving Vertical Stripes", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(10)  # Adjust the delay time between frames (in milliseconds)

        if key != -1:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


width = 800
height = 600
num_stripes = 10
color1 = (255, 0, 0)  # Blue
color2 = (0, 0, 0)  # Black
num_frames = 1000  # Number of frames for the animation
speed = 1  # Speed of the vertical movement
Vstripes(width, height, num_stripes, color1, color2, speed)
```

How it looks:

[image: some gif animation]

Comment: OH i see, thanks for the detailed explanation! Will continue to learn more about it!